# Objective C - Getting user input of unknown type

Tags: objective-c, types, scanf

I'm aware that `scanf()` can be used when you know what data type the user will input. What if that information is unknown, and you would like to be able to handle any type? Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

i.e. assuming some class `whichClass` and function `genericScan()`

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

   whichClass *entry = [[whichClass alloc]init];

   genericScan(&entry);

   if(entry.isDouble())
      NSLog(@"You entered a double!");
   else if(entry.isFloat())
      NSLog(@"You entered a float!");
   else if(entry.isInteger())
      NSLog(@"You entered an integer!");
   else if (entry.isChar())
      NSLog(@"You entered a char!");
   else
      NSLog(@"Unknown data type!");

   return(0);
   }
```

Comment: Take a look at [@encode()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)

Comment: @CodaFi - I think you've misread the question...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `NSScanner`. In outline:

- First obtain your input as an `NSString` in whatever way you wish.
- Now create an `NSScanner` using `+scannerWithString:` or `+localizedScannerWithString:`.
- Now call the various `scanX:` methods; e.g. `scanInteger:`, `scanDouble:`; in an appropriate order; e.g. look for floating point numbers before integers; until you get find a suitable interpretation of the string. Each of these methods returns a `BOOL` indicating whether it was successful in parsing a value.

Note you shouldn't try to distinguish different sized values of the same kind this way; parse them as the largest type of the kind (e.g. `NSDecimalNumber` (if you wish to support those) or `double` for floating point, `long long` for integers) and then use range checks if you wish to find a smaller type that can represent the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would get you what you're aiming for

```
char *data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 256);
fgets(data, 256, stdin);
NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithCString:data];
NSInteger intValue = [dataString integerValue];
// double d = [dataString doubleValue];, etc.
```

That would get whatever data the user entered, and put it's corresponding values in an `int`, `double`, etc. If there is no `integerValue`, for example, it would return 0.